# Oracle Database 12c Installed, but no SQL developer showed up

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I've been trying to use Oracle 12c and SQL Developer on a Virtual Machine running Oracle Linux for weeks now but the process gets worse and worse and this is the fifth time I do the same installation again.
I used oracle-rdbms-server-12cR1-preinstall for the preinstallation process, I also added the groups DBA, OPER, BACKUPDBA, DGDBA, KMDBA, and RACDBA.
I then used the./runInstaller file that comes with the Database and went through the installation process without any issues. But when the installation finished and I closed the installer, there is no trace of SQL Developer anywhere.

I'm not even sure if the Oracle Database was actually installed correctly, I've been running this command to see if it returns me anything in order to check if the database is actually installed but I don't know if i'm correct.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't give up. You can do it!

The daunting part of Oracle Database is that you are installing the exact same binaries for your learning environment as the largest bank on this planet has installed in their production environment! Oracle Database is a very sophisticated RDBMS and it takes years to learn it!

1. Oracle Database and SQL Developer

Oracle Database and SQL Developer are two separate products. You can download both from OTN and install them separately.

2. Database creation

Did you create a database (datafiles) while installing the binaries? There is a checkbox in the installer for that. You can create a database using the tool dbca (Database Creation Assistant) in the $ORACLE_HOME/bin folder.

3. Instance not running.

pmon is a vital process for the instance (processes + memory) which indicates it hasn't started. Check /etc/oratab if there is a database added to the file. If yes, fire up!

```
# set the environment
$. oraenv
ORCLDB
# login as sys and start the database
$sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL>startup
```

Best of luck!

Bjarte

Comment: SQL Developer is included in the database install, you'll see it in $ORACLE_HOME, although it's older than what you'll find on OTN